# Recursive function to compute factorial fails after 20

Tags: java, recursion, factorial

I've written the below Java code to compute factorial of numbers from 1 to 30 recursively. For some reason, the output doesn't match with the [results here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171220135935/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/sets/select/dm_factorial_list.html) for numbers greater than 20. I am surprised to see negative numbers as well.

**Code**

```
class Test {
    
    public static Long factorial(Long number) {
        if(number == 1){
            return 1L;
        }else{
            return number*factorial(number-1);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(final String... arguments){
        for(Long number=1L;number<=30;number++){
            System.out.println("Factorial of " + number + "  : " + factorial(number));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Factorial of 1  : 1
Factorial of 2  : 2
Factorial of 3  : 6
Factorial of 4  : 24
Factorial of 5  : 120
Factorial of 6  : 720
Factorial of 7  : 5040
Factorial of 8  : 40320
Factorial of 9  : 362880
Factorial of 10  : 3628800
Factorial of 11  : 39916800
Factorial of 12  : 479001600
Factorial of 13  : 6227020800
Factorial of 14  : 87178291200
Factorial of 15  : 1307674368000
Factorial of 16  : 20922789888000
Factorial of 17  : 355687428096000
Factorial of 18  : 6402373705728000
Factorial of 19  : 121645100408832000
Factorial of 20  : 2432902008176640000
Factorial of 21  : -4249290049419214848
Factorial of 22  : -1250660718674968576
Factorial of 23  : 8128291617894825984
Factorial of 24  : -7835185981329244160
Factorial of 25  : 7034535277573963776
Factorial of 26  : -1569523520172457984
Factorial of 27  : -5483646897237262336
Factorial of 28  : -5968160532966932480
Factorial of 29  : -7055958792655077376
Factorial of 30  : -8764578968847253504
```

Could somebody please help me to compute factorial up to 30 correctly?

Comment: Look up overflow...

Comment: This is an integer overflow problem. Try using BigInteger.

Comment: You have a case of overflow going on.

Comment: Use `BigInteger`  with `multiply(BigInteger)` .

Comment: Use [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Comment: Complementing.. In order to improve the computation time, you may want to look at Dynamic Programming aswell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what's known as "overflow".  Longs are stored with 64 bits; their maximum value is 2^63 - 1 which is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.  Instead try using a BigInteger.  Using BigInteger is a bit tricky as instantiation and operations are different than normal int/longs.  Here's your code reworked for BigInteger:

```
public class BigIntFactorial {

    public static BigInteger factorial(BigInteger number) {
        if(number.equals(BigInteger.ONE)) {
            return BigInteger.valueOf(1);
        } else {
            return number.multiply(factorial(number.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String... arguments){
        for(Long number=1L;number<=30;number++){

            System.out.println("Factorial of " + number + "  : " + factorial(BigInteger.valueOf(number)));
        }
    }
}
```

output is:

```
Factorial of 1  : 1
Factorial of 2  : 2
Factorial of 3  : 6
Factorial of 4  : 24
Factorial of 5  : 120
Factorial of 6  : 720
Factorial of 7  : 5040
Factorial of 8  : 40320
Factorial of 9  : 362880
Factorial of 10  : 3628800
Factorial of 11  : 39916800
Factorial of 12  : 479001600
Factorial of 13  : 6227020800
Factorial of 14  : 87178291200
Factorial of 15  : 1307674368000
Factorial of 16  : 20922789888000
Factorial of 17  : 355687428096000
Factorial of 18  : 6402373705728000
Factorial of 19  : 121645100408832000
Factorial of 20  : 2432902008176640000
Factorial of 21  : 51090942171709440000
Factorial of 22  : 1124000727777607680000
Factorial of 23  : 25852016738884976640000
Factorial of 24  : 620448401733239439360000
Factorial of 25  : 15511210043330985984000000
Factorial of 26  : 403291461126605635584000000
Factorial of 27  : 10888869450418352160768000000
Factorial of 28  : 304888344611713860501504000000
Factorial of 29  : 8841761993739701954543616000000
Factorial of 30  : 265252859812191058636308480000000
```

Answer (score 4):

It isn't working because you are exceeding the maximum number that can be represented by a long. It has a minimum value of -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 and a maximum value of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (inclusive). The negative numbers are appearing because java rolls over into the negatives when you exceed the max. Find a different way of representing the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have run into the problem that factorials get ridiculously big really fast. Bigger than largest number that can be represented by a long. And in java that means the value "rolls over" and becomes negative.

One solution is to use BigInteger. It has a variable amount of bits, so you can represent almost any size of number in it and you won't run into overflow problems. Note that when i say almost, i mean that biginteger is limited to Integer.MAX_VALUE bits on some implementations, and you shouldn't ever run into that limit.

Another solution would be to represent the numbers with doubles. They have a higher limit than longs, at the cost of losing some precision. I haven't run the numbers, but you should be fine to calculate 30!.

Another cool thing you can do when you really really want to push the limits is use the fft to calculate the multiplication of very high precision numbers. More information here: http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Algorithms/fft.html

edit: ran the numbers, double precision is fine